# How to create an if statement for same file names with different extensions?

Tags: python

**Overview**

Currently, my goal is to show all same file names between 2 folders but under two conditions.

1.) Return do not compare two file names with their extension, can be random

2.) Return file names of specific folder if one file does not exist in another folder.

**Work**

I have two paths I am working with:

```
folder_1= 'C:/Users/gzi/Desktop/test folder/Folder 1'

folder_2 = 'C:/Users/gzi/Desktop/test folder/Folder 2'
```

Inside `Folder 1` there is a file name named

`File number 1.txt`

&

Inside `Folder 2` there is a **similar** file name with a **different extension** along with an extra file:

`File number 1.jpg`

`File number 24.jpg`

**Question**

By looking on my code, I need to set `choices` to return me **all files** from `folder_2`, but if the two folders have similar file names (not including the extension) then do not show that file name.

**My current Code**

```
import os
import glob


folder_1= 'C:/Users/gzu/Desktop/test folder/Folder 1'

folder_2 = 'C:/Users/gzu/Desktop/test folder/Folder 2'

choices = os.listdir(folder_2)
print(choices)
```

**Current output**

```
['File number 1.jpg', 'file number 24.jpg']
```

**Desired output**

```
['File number 24.jpg']
```

This is the output, because the file name (`File number 24`) does not exist inside `Folder 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex to identify files in Folder 1 and then only include files in Folder 2 which don't have a filename in Folder 1.

```
import os
import glob
import re

folder_1 = 'C:/Users/gzu/Desktop/test folder/Folder 1'

folder_2 = 'C:/Users/gzu/Desktop/test folder/Folder 2'

# build a list of all filenames in folder 1, using regex which strips off the file extension
folder_1_filenames = [
       re.sub('\..*', '', f)
       for f in os.listdir(folder_1)
]

# choices then becomes every file in folder 2 if the filename is not in folder_1_filenames    
choices = [
      f for f in os.listdir(folder_2)
      if re.sub('\..*', '', f) not in folder_1_filenames
]

print(choices)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time in answering the question! Do you mind please explaining it?

Comment: sure, have added some comments